# Test if an integer is an index value of a slice

Tags: python, slice

Is there a Boolean function to test whether an integer is an index value contained in a `slice` object without unpacking the `start`, `stop`, and `step` parameters?

```
3 in slice(1, 6, 2)
```

raises an error as slices are not iterable.

The predicate should work for arbitrary `None`, `start`, `stop`, `step` parameters. The logic is straightforward but hoping there's a built in or package.

Comment: Does it need to support negative indices? What is the desired output of `123 in slice(None, -1, None)`?

Answer (score 11):

The logic is not as straightforward as you think, since it doesn't make sense to do this for a `None` stop or start (depending on the sign of `step`), since you need to specify a length.

Essentially, what you are asking for is containment in a [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) object, which holds the same information as a slice, but is a valid sequence, and supports fast containment checking. [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) has a method called [`indices`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slice.indices) to help with the transformation, if you provide the length of the sequence you are interested in slicing:

```
def in_slice(n, s, length):
    return n in range(*s.indices(length))
```

Comment: What is the point of the `slice.indices` method since `range(*s.indices(length))` is equal to `range(length)[s]`?

Comment: @Maggyero. `range(length)[s]` constructs two ranges. It's just a longer way to get the same result, though you could argue that ranges are cheap and it's easier to understand than what I suggest.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that both `slice.indices` and `range.__getitem__` use the same underlying C function [`_PySlice_GetLongIndices`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.4/Objects/sliceobject.c#L376-L378) in CPython.

Comment: @Maggyero. I'm not all that surprised

Comment: @MadPhysicist. This is the documentation for `slice.indices`: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slice.indices

Comment: @omsrisagar. Thanks. I've been looking for that for years.

Answer (score 0):

If you can select an appropriately sized range, you can apply the slice to it and determine if the index will be in the range.

for positive/None boundaries, this is merely a matter of having a big enough range to contain the index itself:

```
i in range(i+1)[slice(start,stop,step)]

3 in range(7)[slice(1,6,2)] --> True
```

In order to support negative boundaries (in particular a negative start), you'll need to ensure that index offset from start is a multiple of the step and that the size is small enough to include the index.  This is under the assumption that there exists a range size that will contain the index.  Otherwise you'll have to supply a range size yourself:

```
def inSlice(i,s, size = None):
    if size is None:
        step  = s.step  or 1
        start = s.start or 0
        size  = size or i+1
        if step < 0 or start <= 0:
           size = (i-min(0,start))//step*step - int(s.stop is None)
    return  i in range(size)[s]
```

This will provide the following results:

```
inSlice( 3 , slice(1, 6, 2) )           -->  True ( size = 4 )
inSlice( 37000216 , slice(10, 100000000, 3) )   -->  True ( size = 37000217 )
inSlice( 17 , slice(-100, 10, -3) )     -->  True ( size = 117 )
inSlice( 17 , slice(-100, -10, 3) )     -->  True ( size = 117 )
inSlice( 97 , slice(100, None, -3) )    -->  True ( size = 98 )
inSlice( 107 , slice(None, 100, -3) )   -->  True ( size = 108 )
inSlice( 97 , slice(-10, None, -3) )    -->  True ( size = 107 )
```